# Select from a DB2 table and insert to a SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, db2

I feel like this might be a crazy question, and if anyone has a better idea of how to do it, by all means please let me know.

I have a .Net C# project at work that validates certain tables against the company standards they must adhere to.  The tables can be on SQL Server or DB2.  When a table is initially added to the program, I gather the metadata/information about the table using select statements off of either `information_schema.columns` for sql, or `syscat.columns` for db2.  Once I get that data, I store it in a table (let's call it `all_table_information`) on sql server containing that same information for every table that is validated in the program.

If the table is a SQL table, I can run this query (of course restricting it to only the columns from the table I want):

```
insert into [all_table_information]
    (table_id, column_name, data_type, max_char_length)
select table_id, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
    from information_schema.columns 
    where ...restrict to needed table...
```

And then execute that in a SqlCommand.  But if it is a DB2 table, I have to run this query (restricted again to the columns I need):

```
select tabschema, tabname, colname, typename, length 
from syscat.columns 
where ...restrict to needed table...
```

Then get a DataReader with the results and loop through it inserting each row using:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
   insert into [all_table_information]
   (table_id, column_name, data_type, max_char_length) values 
   (..."'" + dr["whatever"] + "', '" + ....)

   ...execute sql here...

} 
dr.Close();
```

Doing it this way works, but it is slow, so I was just wondering if there was anyway to do this in one statement?  I know you could save the db2 table information to a data table as well, but can you run a query against a data table directly?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use SqlBulkCopy:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

It is much faster than doing individual inserts for each row.

Comment: This class have limitation for other DBs :
The SqlBulkCopy class can be used to write data only to SQL Server tables.

Comment: Yes but my understanding is that Ryan wants to store it all into a SQL Server database table so SqlBulkCopy would be valid for his use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SSIS, rather than writing an app to do it?

Comment: Can you call SSIS from within .Net?  The table the column information comes from is determined from a series of combo box selections within the program.

Comment: Believe you can - you certainly could with DTS packages "back in the day"

Answer (score 1):

You would do better to create your `SqlCommand` outside of the `dr.Read()` and use parameters. This will increase performance and security, and you won't have to worry about properly forming your syntax dynamically. Like this...

```
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(connection);

insertCommand.CommandText = @"
insert into [all_table_information]
(table_id, column_name, data_type, max_char_length)
values
(@table_id, @column_name, @data_type, @max_char_length)";

...create your parameters and add them here

insertCommand.Prepare(); //precompiles the query
while (dr.Read())
{
    ...set parameter values

    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
} 
dr.Close();
```